# $d$ is finer than $d'$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I have $E$ endowed with two metrics $d$ and $d'=\ln(1+d)$

How to prove that $d$ is finer than $d'$; that is how to prove that:

For all $x\in E$ any open ball for $d'$ contains an open ball for $d$?

Comment: "finner then"$\to$"finer than"

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @martin.koeberl i fund that $B_{d'}(x,r)=B_{d}(x,e^r-1)$

Comment: So what is left to do? (You should always include your attempts so far in the question and say why you need help. That makes it easier for others.)

Comment: how to find that for every $x$ and any r >0, $B_{d}\subset B_{d'}$

Comment: @martin.koeberl i need your help please to find a closed ball, $B_{d'}'(0,1)$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ where $d'=\ln(1+d_1)$ and $d_1(X,Y)=|x_1-y_1|+|x_2-y_2|$ i found $$B'_{d'}(0,1)=\{X\in\mathbb{R}^2, |x_1|+|x_2|\leq \exp{(1)}-1\}$$ how to continue please

Answer (score 0):

It also can be easily proved that for $x>0$, $ln(1+x)\leq x$, which shows that for all $x,y\in E$, $$d'(x,y)\leq d(x,y)$$. This implies that $$B_d(x,\epsilon) \subseteq B_{d'}(x,\epsilon)$$ for all $x,\epsilon \in R$.

There is another way to find that. Using the result you found:
$$B_{d'}(x,\epsilon) = B_d(x, e^{\epsilon} - 1)$$ So we also trivially get that for any $x,\epsilon \in R$, $$B_d(x, e^{\epsilon} - 1) \subseteq B_{d'}(x,\epsilon) $$
Thus every open $d'$-ball contains an open $d$-ball.

Comment: if i don't know this, i calculate $B_{d'}(x,r)=B_{d}(x, e^r-1)$ how to continue please

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: but we need the same radius $r$ no?